# Remote branch on Github won't allow deletion

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to delete a remote branch. It's 4 years old and I've never used it. I have followed the instructions I have found on SF and other sites, yet the command as given refuses to work.

The result of `git branch -r` is:

```
origin/dev
origin/master
origin/maxxo_rspec_reorg
```

And so, the command as I have understood it to delete that remote branch is:

```
git push origin --delete maxxo_rspec_reorg 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa_me':
```

This is the unfortunate part:

```
error: unable to delete 'maxxo_rspec_reorg': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myuser/myapp.git'
```

That's clearly not true at all. The remote branch DOES exist. Am I referring to the branch name incorrectly somehow? I tried prefixing it with "origin/" but that didn't work either.

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: As @Tomáš pointed out in his answer the branch might not exist on origin. You can check easy enough with a `git fetch origin && git branch -r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If github says it doesn't exist, perhaps it indeed doesn't. You may wish to perform

```
git remote prune origin
```

every once in a while to remove stale remote-tracking branches. You can even configure to have it done automatically on every `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git remote update`:

```
git config fetch.prune true
```